# iOS How to pass data from UIViewController to destinationViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to pass data from MainViewController to specific (It depends on user's choice in GoogleMap) view controller. In MainVC I have NSArray, which is called: userData.
The code is:

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"FirstViewController", @"First",
                                      @"SecondViewController", @"Second",
                                      nil];
    NSString *viewControllerIdentifier = [tempDictionary valueForKey:[marker.userData valueForKey:@"controller"]];
    UIViewController *destViewController = [iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerIdentifier];
    //destViewController.placeData = marker.userData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
```

`//destViewController.placeData = marker.userData;` doesn't exist.
Should I add this NSArray inside UIViewController implementation? Or any ideas?
Thank you, Artem :)

Comment: uh, you want to pass data to destViewController ? I don't understand what is the "previously" VC in this example ...

Comment: Yes, From MainVC to destViewController. Sry for my bad eng :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that, the viewController instantiate in your storyboard can handle those data, just create your own ViewController Class that manage this NSArray

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray placeData;

@end
```

and in your sample code :

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"FirstViewController", @"First",
                                  @"SecondViewController", @"Second",
                                  nil];
NSString *viewControllerIdentifier = [tempDictionary valueForKey:[marker.userData valueForKey:@"controller"]];
MyViewController *destViewController = (MyViewController *)[iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerIdentifier];
destViewController.placeData = marker.userData;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
```

Once this is done, all your viewControllers (assuming there are more than 1) can use this one as mother class